# DI - Overused or Bad Design?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

There are couple of situations where team mates does not agree on how to use DI.

1. I need a new instance for each loop. I cannot pass job instance to class ctor.

   ```
   for(var item in items){
      var job = new Job();
      job.execute(item)
   }
   ```

   One option is to inject the `IContainer` to the class and use `container.Resolve<Job>()`. But this is anti-pattern and container is exposed. Another option is to inject a factory and inject container to factory. Factory method will eventually use `container.Resolve<T>()` This is slight different but container still exposed and is anti pattern.
2. Common places where injected class got corrupted, for example, WCF clients, if in defaulted state, we need new client. I understand, most containers handle it, still how can I create a fresh  instance of injected class when I need. This is required for better control. One example, if WCF connection once created and closed or defaulted, class should not be able recreate the client. Windsor for example, will create new client instance if closed or defaulted.
3. Once method in my class has dependency of disposable class. Injecting disposable to the class, seems bad idea to me. Since it is being used only in one method still need to inject irrespective of other method being called. And it cannot be disposed if dependent class is being used for long time. I could use `using` construct in method itself.
4. My service class has dependencies on too many repositories, each one of them being used in exactly one method. Injecting all repositories does not make sense to me, although there are little impact on performance. I recommend injecting repository factory, but then it will become anti-pattern and container needs to be injected into factory.
5. My code reviewer is biased (or me), he does not like to see new key word used to create instance. For him, since I am using new, it is not testable code and I am not following DI. So I cannot create even new DTO's like `DefaultPaymentOption` has to be injected into `Order` instance. If I inject `DefaultPaymentOption` class into `Order`, I loose simplicity of DTO and it also violates the DB data. `DefaultPaymentOption` is not required for orders in draft mode. Are we overdoing DI? In my understanding, DI should be used for objects to do some action from external world not for composition.
6. Another issue I faced with "Not New" approach, I have to expose internal class of library to public (meant only for that library) to register in bootstrapper from host application. For example, CustomJobExecuter (of type IJobExecutor) in CustomJob library needs to be register in host app, and to inject it, I need to expose it. While I could only register CustomJobManager and create new instance of CustomJobExecutor and use it.

Answer (score 1):

One guiding problem I see with your approach to DI comes from a misunderstanding of what it is used **for**. You want to use DI when you're trying to abstract the *implementation details* of the system into small classes that are individually tested via unit tests. If you create an concrete class that has an internal class inside of it, most likely your class is going too much work and should be broken out in to constituent parts that are unit tested. This way when something breaks, you know almost immediately what the problem is based on what part of the code broke.

I would read up on SOLID design principals and unit testing, more in-depth, to understand the purpose behind these patterns more solidly.

1. At some point you're going to need to do some actual work, and it's perfectly fine to new up an instance of something in order to do it. For instance, when interacting with db2/AS400, we don't have the options to write tests against our dataservice tier, and the dataservice tier news up instances of connections in order to write data.
2. This is dependent on your DI container, and would be a separate question. I know in SimpleInjector you can do a RegisterPerRequest call that requires new instances be returned each time.
3. The disposable class is an implementation detail, and you can freely new up an instance in order to keep the implementation detail restricted to that particular class. Alternately, you could wrap it in a layer that handles the disposal logic after the required responsibility is fulfilled.
4. It sounds like your service is becoming a god object and has too many responsibilities. What is this one service's responsibility?
5. Look into automapper for DTO, as it will allow you to mock IMappingEngine and enable unit testing through mocking the calls to var dto = mappingEngine.Map(model);
6. Yes, you will need to make internal classes public if they are going to be tested.

Comment: Ad 6:
Each library might have a single public method (in a public class) that is provided with a container and registers all its implementations to it. This method would be called from the host application (that owns the container instance). 

Use [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to access implementations in a test assembly – I believe this is one of the best use cases for the attribute.

No need to expose internal classes…

Answer (score 0):

from my point of view there is nothing wrong with `new` keyword. it's part of the language so it can be used but as everything else you have to use it wisely. DI was invented to make code more testable, modular and easier to maintain

if `job` in your example has no dependencies that requires container (repositories, services etc), is testable and doesn't introduce new cycles to yours dependencies then, imho, `new` is completely ok. if, in future, you need dependencies from container then you will replace `new` with `container.get(...)`. same with DTOs - getting them from container is overkill, as they should have no logic and no dependencies

and you don't have to make your classes public. 1) some languages offers more visibility scopes than public and private (java for example - default scope). 2) you don't have to test each class separately - it's called unit testing, not class testing. but sad truth is: sometimes you will have to relax visibility for easier testing

Answer (score 0):

When you need an instance at runtime, you should always turn to [Abstract Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) to provide it, not your DI container. You apparently are assuming that the DI container is supposed to create every instance everywhere, but that puts you squarely into anti-pattern territory because there is hardly an application in existence that doesn't need to create short-lived instances.

```
public interface ISomeObject
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface ISomeConfigurationDependency
{
    // A dependency that is configured in the DI container.
}

public interface ISomeRuntimeDependency
{
    // A dependency created by some other factory at runtime.
}

public interface ISomeObjectFactory
{
    ISomeObject Create(string someRuntimeValue, ISomeRuntimeDependency someRuntimeDependency);
    void Release(ISomeObject someObject);
}

public class SomeObject : ISomeObject
{
    private readonly string someRuntimeValue;
    private readonly string someConfigurationValue;
    private readonly ISomeRuntimeDependency someRuntimeDependency;
    private readonly ISomeConfigurationDependency someConfigurationDependency;

    public SomeObject(
        string someRuntimeValue, 
        string someConfigurationValue, 
        ISomeRuntimeDependency someRuntimeDependency, 
        ISomeConfigurationDependency someConfigurationDependency)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someRuntimeValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someRuntimeValue");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someConfigurationValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someConfigurationValue");
        if (someRuntimeDependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someRuntimeDependency");
        if (someConfigurationDependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someConfigurationDependency");

        this.someRuntimeValue = someRuntimeValue;
        this.someConfigurationValue = someConfigurationValue;
        this.someRuntimeDependency = someRuntimeDependency;
        this.someConfigurationDependency = someConfigurationDependency;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am using the dependencies now");
    }
}


public class SomeObjectFactory : ISomeObjectFactory
{
    private readonly string someConfigurationValue;
    private readonly ISomeConfigurationDependency someConfigurationDependency;

    public SomeObjectFactory(string someConfigurationValue, ISomeConfigurationDependency someConfigurationDependency)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someConfigurationValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someConfigurationValue");
        if (someConfigurationDependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someConfigurationDependency");

        this.someConfigurationValue = someConfigurationValue;
        this.someConfigurationDependency = someConfigurationDependency;
    }

    public ISomeObject Create(string someRuntimeValue, ISomeRuntimeDependency someRuntimeDependency)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someRuntimeValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someRuntimeValue");
        if (someRuntimeDependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someRuntimeDependency");

        // The only thing a factory does is new up an instance - 
        // no business logic here. There is nothing to test  
        // here because nothing can go wrong.
        return new SomeObject(
            someRuntimeValue, 
            this.someConfigurationValue, 
            someRuntimeDependency, 
            this.someConfigurationDependency);
    }

    // Use release if you want to expose the factory as a formal extension point
    // that might have unmanaged dependencies.
    public void Release(ISomeObject someObject)
    {
        var disposable = someObject as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly ISomeObjectFactory someObjectFactory;
    private readonly ISomeRuntimeDependencyFactory someRuntimeDependencyFactory;

    public SomeService(ISomeObjectFactory someObjectFactory, ISomeRuntimeDependencyFactory someRuntimeDependencyFactory)
    {
        if (someObjectFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someObjectFactory");
        if (someRuntimeDependencyFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someRuntimeDependencyFactory");

        this.someObjectFactory = someObjectFactory;
        this.someRuntimeDependencyFactory = someRuntimeDependencyFactory;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Setup runtime variables
        var someRuntimeValue = "test";
        var someRuntimeDependency = this.someRuntimeDependencyFactory.Create();

        // Get a runtime instance
        var someObject = this.someObjectFactory.Create(someRuntimeValue, someRuntimeDependency);
        try
        {
            someObject.DoSomething();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.someObjectFactory.Release(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

So, you would need to wire up your SomeService, SomeObjectFactory, someConfigurationValue and SomeRuntimeDependencyFactory to be injected with DI. The SomeObject instances are nicely created and cleaned up (if the SomeObject concrete type implements IDisposable) at runtime by SomeObjectFactory.

SomeRuntimeDependencyFactory would be exactly the same as SomeObjectFactory - it just runs the new keyword and optionally supplies dependencies to the new instance. The exact dependencies depend on the concrete type. Note that the dependencies are not part of the interface.

You can test your SomeObject and SomeService classes just fine in this scenario. There is no reason to test an abstract factory because there is absolutely nothing that can go wrong with the new keyword. Nothing. So the new keyword is not your enemy here. Just make sure that your factory does nothing else except create the instance or you will be creating business logic that cannot be tested.

As for having too many dependencies on a single service, this is a code smell that indicates you are probably breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. You need to refactor the services into [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

As for making a library DI Friendly, see [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/). Or follow the link within if you in fact have a framework and are trying to have the host application plug into it.